# leak using SecPKCS12Import

Tags: objective-c, ssl, memory-leaks, ssl-certificate

I have a memory leak in the following code. certificateData and passphrase are NSObject, so they are under ARC. I release keyRef immediately after using the function.

```
CFArrayRef keyRef;
OSStatus status = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)certificateData, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)@{(__bridge NSString *)kSecImportExportPassphrase: passphrase}, &keyRef);
CFRelease(keyRef);
```

The leak instrument detects the following leak: (And don't detect when I comment the previous lines)

```
Leaked Object   #   Address         Size        Responsible Library     Responsible Frame
Malloc 96 Bytes 1   0x7f8458def240  96 Bytes    Security                DefaultAllocator::malloc(unsigned long)
```

Am I missing something?